# Custom table section footer view - label not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a new Single-view project (using storyboard) in Xcode with a single UITableViewController. Here is the setup code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    _footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 44, 44)];
    l.text = @"Label Label Label Label Label Label Label Label Label";
    l.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [_footerView addSubview:l];

    _footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _footerView.frame.size.height;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _footerView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

I want the label in the custom table footer view to be drawn at x = 60, but when I run the project, at first the label is invisible (in portrait, screen attached). Then if I rotate once, it becomes visible and if I rotate back to portrait it's visible.

What am I missing?

[image: Label not visible]
[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be initialising your footer view with a width and height of 44px, yet adding the label outside of its bounds.

Try the following instead:

```
_footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), 44)];

_footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(_footerView.bounds, 60.0f, 0.0f)];
l.text = @"Label Label Label Label Label Label Label Label Label";
l.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[_footerView addSubview:l];

_footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

As a further point, try not to use `[UIColor clearColor]` as a label background colour if you can help it - it significantly reduces scrolling performance. In this case you should use `[UIColor lightGrayColor]` so it matches its superview.